# underline only half of the word in reactjs and material ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This is what i am trying to recreate
[image: This is what i am trying to recreate]

This is what i have managed so far[image]

I am using materialui and reactjs.This is the code.

```
bodyTitle: {
fontWeight: 800,
paddingTop: theme.spacing(5),
paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
color: "white",
display: "inline-flex",
flexGrow: 1,
width: "75%",
textDecoration: "underline",
textDecorationColor: "blue",
```

},

```
 <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.bodyTitle}>
    Upcoming
 </Typography>
```

How do Underline only half the word?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below method

```
<span className={classes.Classname}>Up</span>coming
```

.Classname{
textDecoration: "underline",
textDecorationColor: "blue"
}